# Can't display multiple components in a Singular Page Application (Angular)

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, mqtt

I'm trying to develop a basic website in which I have to display data (dashboard), received from an MQTT topic. I can't display the second component, which is a gauge that should display the data received from the MQTT broker. I don't know how to connect this graphical plugin to the broker.

I already tried to troubleshoot the problem by developing a new stand-alone application where I showed only the gauge element.
I found different kind of gauges libraries.

App.component.html:

```
 Speed: {{value}}
  app-gauge /app-gauge
```

Gauge.component.ts

```
export class GaugeComponent implements OnInit {
  public value$: Observable<number>;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.value$ = interval(1000).pipe(
      map(() => Math.random() * 120)
    );
```

The gauge should appear and starts to generate/show random numbers (link to the guide that i've followed: http://www.wayneparrott.com/add-a-realtime-gauge-to-your-angular-project/)

Comment: Is the html of your `app.component.html` is same as in your question?

Comment: Yes. I've tried to put  "<app-gauge> </app-gauge>" in the index.html,with no result. The second component "gauge" only shows up (but doesn't start) if i put it in the app.component.html (the main one).

Comment: Without angle brackets your html is invalid. Have you checked you console for errors?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, it seems that your component is showing but the `value` is not changing in your html. The reason for that is because you are using `Observable` to emit random values after every 1s so in order to get this to work you need to subscribe to that `Observable` which in this case is `value$`. You can subscribe to it using `async` pipe.

There are also some code that you need to change. You are defining your `Observable` in `gauge.component.ts` but you are accessing it in `app.component.html`

Move your code from `guage.component.ts` to `app.component.ts`

Your `app.component.ts` should look like this:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public value$: Observable<number>;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.value$ = interval(1000).pipe(
      map(() => Math.random() * 120)
    );
```

Now change your `app.component.html` to something like this:

```
Speed: {{ value$ | async }}
  <app-gauge> </app-gauge>
```

Comment: Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
'radial-gauge' is not a known element:
1. If 'radial-gauge' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'radial-gauge' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

Comment: This is the error that the chrome's console returns to me

Comment: Kindly see my code i've used `app-guage` not `radial-gauge`

Comment: you are using `radial-gauge` inside your html, that's why you are getting this error

Comment: Now is giving me this:

Comment: ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at new DebugContext_ (core.js:11182)
    at getCurrentDebugContext (core.js:11358)
    at DebugRenderer2.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.DebugRenderer2.createElement (core.js:11399)
    at createElement (core.js:8118)
    at createViewNodes (core.js:10360)
    at callViewAction (core.js:10715)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:10634)
    at createViewNodes (core.js:10427)
    at callViewAction (core.js:10715)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:10634)

Comment: Where did you put `<app-gauge> </app-gauge>`

Comment: in app.component.html

Comment: also,take a look at this (need help):

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56183187/ngx-gauge-doesnt-show-the-received-data