# ngx-gauge doesn't show the received data

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I am developing a page that shows real-time data from a server. Now i'm testing it with some mqtt client websocket (like hivemq). The value itself that i receive is showed in the chrome console,but i'm trying to make this value graphical with NGX-GAUGE.
The ngx-gauge is showed correctly in the page,and if i put in "gaugeValue" a standard number it works (also with a Math.Random), but if i take a value from a MQTT broker,it just doesn't do anything

when i try to get the value from an MQTT broker, the value and green line of the ngx-gauge (which should increase/decrease in real time) doesn't do anything

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Paho } from 'ng2-mqtt/mqttws31';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {


  valore:String;    

  gaugeType = "semi";
  gaugeValue=this.valore;
  gaugeLabel = "Valore";
  gaugeAppendText = "km/hr";s
  animate=true;
  duration=1500;

  private client;
  mqttbroker = 'broker.mqttdashboard.com';

  ngOnInit() {
    this.client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(this.mqttbroker, Number(8000), 'client1');
    this.client.onMessageArrived=this.onMessageArrived.bind(this);
    this.client.onConnectionLost=this.onConnectionLost.bind(this);
    this.client.connect({onSuccess: this.onConnect.bind(this)});
   }

  onConnect() {
    console.log('onConnect');
    this.client.subscribe('testtopic/40/xxx');
  }

  onConnectionLost(responseObject) {
    if (responseObject.errorCode !== 0) {
      console.log('onConnectionLost:' + responseObject.errorMessage);
    }
  }

  onMessageArrived(message) {
    console.log('onMessageArrived: ' + message.destinationName + ': ' + message.payloadString);

    if (message.destinationName.indexOf('xxx') !== -1) {
      this.valore = (message.payloadString);
    }
  }
}
```

It should simply show the value,with the line respondig in real time with that value

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue but I solved it after writing code by this way :

```
gaugeValue= 0; //define minimum value in export

this.gaugeValue= (message.payloadString);  // intead of "this.valore" use this.gaugeValue
```

Please refer screenshot 1 & 2 for more understandings;
[I used _thoughput_gaugeValue for defining](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mV28w.png)

[same _thoughput_gaugeValue  is used as  this._thoughput_gaugeValue for getting data. Do not declare _thoughput_gaugeValue:any](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oE4T.png)